# Display 2nd 'column' value of array in separate screen based on selected row in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I just started to learn swift and trying to make a simple app in which I have created a `UITableView` with terms

> ('Term 1' till 'Term 15') and want to display a detail description of the term
>
> ('Detail 1' till 'Detail 15') when selected in the table in a separate view.

Using the available online tutorials, I've created the code below but have difficulties to complete and am only able to display a fixed string.

Any suggestions how best to proceed are welcome:

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    let Datasource = [("Term 1","Detail 1"),("Term 2","Detail 2"),("Term 3","Detail 3"),("Term 4","Detail 4"),("Term 5","Detail 5"),("Term 6","Detail 6"),("Term 7","Detail 7"),("Term 8","Detail 8"),("Term 9","Detail 9"),("Term 10","Detail 10"),("Term 11","Detail 11"),("Term 12","Detail 12"),("Term 13","Detail 13"),("Term 14","Detail 14"),("Term 15","Detail 15")]

    //MARK -> Table Structure
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.Datasource.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        var (Id, Detail) = Datasource[indexPath.row]
        Cell.textLabel?.text = Id
        return Cell        
    }

    //MARK -> Link to view term details on seperate screen
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedTableViewController        
        DestinationViewController.DetailedTerm = "DISPLAY 2ND COLUMN OF DATASOURCE ARREY"        
    }

    //MARK -> Standard methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use Array of Dictionaries.